# Code for Comment box with like and comment option

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I am creating a website in which i want to include comment box similar as facebook which has reply and like option for any comment. So, i therefore need code for this. I am using C#.net and SQL server. Please if any1 have code for comment box with reply and like options then only  post the code...At present i am using comment box using repeater that doesn't have reply and like option for the comment as in facebook or any social site

Thanks

Comment: http://disqus.com, they haz the codez :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use facebook comment box instead of creating your own unless you have a any requirement that is not fulfilled by facebook comment box ?

**[Comments Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)**

**For SEO:**
You can access all the comments left on your site via the graph API. Simply grab the comments from the API and render them in the body of your page behind the comments box.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, facebook comments are not indexable by search engines.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It depends how you implement it. Nobody stops you from using Graph API provided by facebook for pulling the comments & placing it on the page for SEO purpose.

Comment: yeah, but why bother with facebook comment box then? Implementing own solution will be simpler.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Have you get a chance to try out facebook comment box ? Have a look at this http://www.driveinside.com/upcoming-cars/ford-ecosport/128/. It have many features integrated in it - Comments, reply, like, moderation tools, asynchronous load, Load More Comments load on request, multiple login providers....

Comment: Yeah, I did try them, actually. Moved back to wordpress comments, and then to Disqus.